# Start flask app from console - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, flask, python-import

Why, when I try to run a flask application from the console, I encounter an error: ModuleNotFoundError:

```
$ python run.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.app.controller import app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

or

```
$ env FLASK_APP=run.py flask run
 * Serving Flask app "run.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

Error: While importing "run", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pronect/PycharmProjects/it-informer-master/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "/home/pronect/PycharmProjects/it-informer-master/src/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.app.controller import app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Here is a project screenshot:
[image]

But if I run the application from Paycharm, then everything works fine.
How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to change the code to this:

```
from app.controller import app
from config import Config
```

The file run.py is already in the directory src. The error occurs, because there is no other folder called src in the directory where the file run.py is stored.